# Return blank records instead of No Records found from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-communities

I am working on mobile app using SalesForce Mobile SDK and for a functionality to work, I am building the mapping between the customer_id and corresponding Address. So to have a mapping, I have modified the SOQL Query to get the customer_id value back once the query is executed.

This mapping works fine when there is Address is found. But when there is no address associated, I doesnot get any response. So, mapping a customer_id and put a null address in it, I would need the customer_id back even when address is not found.

To better explain: The following query doesnot return any result since there is no address found:

```
SELECT Account_vod__c,Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c, Name FROM Address_vod__c WHERE Account_vod__c = '001e000000qVp8WAAS'
```

But I want to create a query such that if there are no records found, it would return something like:

[image]

Comment: select customer id from the customer table (assuming there is such a thing), and then left-join from the customer table to the address table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested SOQL queries did the trick:

```
SELECT Id, Name,(SELECT Id, Account_vod__c, Name, Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c FROM Address_vod__r)FROM Account WHERE Id = '001e0000008Ch5nAAC' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try by using coalesce

```
SELECT coalesce(Account_vod__c,001e000000qVp8WAAS),
Address_line_2_vod__c, City_vod__c, Name 
FROM Address_vod__c WHERE Account_vod__c = '001e000000qVp8WAAS'
```

Comment: Thanks Zaynul. Looks like coalesce is not supported by Salesforce SOQL. So, giving me an error: "Malformed Query". Edited the tags for the question for SOQL only.

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION BASED ON INITIAL DBMS TAG :

```
SELECT a.Account_vod__c, a1.Address_line_2_vod__c, a1.City_vod__c, a1.Name
FROM (SELECT '001e000000qVp8WAAS' AS Account_vod__c) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Address_vod__c a1
     ON a1.Account_vod__c = a.Account_vod__c;
```

If you have more than one `Account_vod__c`s then use `UNION ALL` & do `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT a.Account_vod__c, a1.Address_line_2_vod__c, a1.City_vod__c, a1.Name
FROM (SELECT '001e000000qVp8WAAS' AS Account_vod__c
      UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Address_vod__c a1
     ON a1.Account_vod__c = a.Account_vod__c;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I am a novice of Salesforce SOQL. Looks like SOQL doesn't work the same way as SQL. Giving me an error "MALFORMED_QUERY: 
FROM ( SELECT '001e000000qVp8WAAS' AS
^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:5
unexpected token: '('"

Comment: Edited the tags. Thanks again